# Using TPL and Rx in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, system.reactive, task-parallel-library

I want to use the AsyncCtpLibrary_Silverlight.dll in my Silverlight project and I want also to use Rx (for processing event streams in de UI).
The problem is that AsyncCtpLibrary_Silverlight.dll and System.CoreEx.dll (From Rx) both define System.AggregateException, which causes conflicts.
Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx). It allows you to explicitly reference classes in your code even if they are in the same namespace and have the same name.

You might, for example, reference the Rx classes like so:

```
extern alias rx;

//... further down

rx::System.AggregateException aeRx = null;
System.AggregateException aeAsync = null;
```

The "rx" alias also has to be added to the property page for the DLL reference in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you never have to declare the type yourself, there should be no problem.  If you can use type inference, the compiler can make local variables of the types from the appropriate assemblies.